# Sessions in CodeIgniter hinder each other

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm making a CMS using CodeIgniter. I'm using modules to separate the admin part of the site from the normal site. I make use of session to store some data, this is working great but i got 1 problem.

When i login in the Admin panel it makes a session so I know I’m logged in. When I go to the normal site and return to admin and refresh my page I’m logged out. It seems like when I go to the normal site it first clears the session or it overwrite the old session. I think this comes because of the session name used by CodeIgniter.

now my question :p

Is it possible to set different session names for the admin module and the normal site?

I hope I have made ​​myself clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice if you handle session with db in CI

yes it's possible please use seperate session for both and on logout unset seperate session what session you want to unset.
like you create session for front:-

```
$this->session->set_userdata('user_account_login',$data);
```

on logout you need :-

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('user_account_login');
```

same for admin but in different var :-

```
$this->session->set_userdata('admin_account_login',$data);
```

on logout you need :-

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('admin_account_login');
```

Comment: I think i didnt make myself clear. When i go to front i resets the whole session. So it ressets this: $_SESSION['ci_session'].

Comment: please add your data in session CI will auto handle session if you have seperated that and on logout not destroy full session

Comment: thats also what i thought but it dont. I testing the sessions again and found out that he complete delets the session when i go back to admin. I think this is a isseu of the module system im using.

Comment: I found the problem, in the CI controller there was a $this->session->sess_destroy();. But i didnt know, some one has set it and i dont know why. Any way thank you for you help ;)